# need implement C# Counter

Tags: c#, counter

I want to make increment and decrement counter.
There are two buttons called X and Y. If first press X and then press Y counter should increment.
If first press Y and then press X counter should decrement.

I am not familiar with c#. So can anyone help me please ??  :(

Comment: Is this homework?  If not, wouldn't it be wildly simpler to just have an "Increment" button and a "Decrement" button?  If so, what have you tried so far?

Comment: And would that be ASP.NET, WPF or WinForms buttons?

Comment: Do you want a web or desktop application? Are you looking for the complete code or do you want pointers to different resources (how to create a application, how to do the logic, how to display the results)? Is there a programming language you do know so we can make analogies?

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you need 2 variables: a counter, and the last button pressed.  I'll assume this is a WinForms application, since you did not specify at the time I am writing this.

```
class MyForm : Form
{
    // From the designer code:
    Button btnX;
    Button btnY;

    void InitializeComponent()
    {
        ...
        btnX.Clicked += btnX_Clicked;
        btnY.Clicked += btnY_Clicked;
        ...
    }

    Button btnLastPressed = null;
    int counter = 0;

    void btnX_Clicked(object source, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (btnLastPressed == btnY)
        {
            // button Y was pressed first, so decrement the counter
            --counter;
            // reset the state for the next button press
            btnLastPressed = null;
        }
        else
        {
            btnLastPressed = btnX;
        }
    }

    void btnY_Clicked(object source, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (btnLastPressed == btnX)
        {
            // button X was pressed first, so increment the counter
            ++counter;
            // reset the state for the next button press
            btnLastPressed = null;
        }
        else
        {
            btnLastPressed = btnY;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You would want to have a variable that you want to keep track of the counter.

```
int counter = 0;
```

If it is a web application then you must store this some where such as session state.
then in your increment counter button:

```
counter++;
```

and in your decrement counter button do this:

```
counter--;
```

Answer (score 0):

Found this on another website:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
        //create a global private integer 
        private int number;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            //Intialize the variable to 0
            number = 0;
            //Probably a good idea to intialize the label to 0 as well
            numberLabel.Text = number.ToString();
        }
        private void Xbutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //On a X Button click increment the number
            number++;
            //Update the label. Convert the number to a string
            numberLabel.Text = number.ToString();
        }
        private void Ybutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //If number is less than or equal to 0 pop up a message box
            if (number <= 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Cannot decrement anymore. Value will be  
                                                negative");
            }
            else
            {
                //decrement the number
                number--;
                numberLabel.Text = number.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
```