# How can I make my Decrement method ask for a user input how muh to count down every step down

Tags: c#, counter, decrement

so my problem is , that my Counter method Decrement should ask for the number to count down every single time it counts a step down so like lets say - it counts 1 down then it should be a user input - if they enter a number like 6 - then it should count down 6 and so on every step down.

This is my code but it doesn't do anything other than simply count down.

thanks!

```
class BackCounterB:CCounter
    {
        private int step;
        private int levelalt;
        public int Step
        {
            get
            {
                return step;
            }

            set
            {
                step = value;
            }
        }

        public BackCounterB(int step, int start_, int limit_) : base(start_, limit_)

        {
            Step = step;
            
        }

        

        public void Decrement()
        {
            
            
            levelalt = Level;
            Level -= Step; //level - step
            if (levelalt < Level)
                    Step = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            
            if (Level < Start) Level = Limit; //Level < start ... 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What value is Step first time Decrement is called - 0 ? You should be able to see what's going on by debugging your code.

Comment: @aubug "step" is just an integer that I used - I added my entire class now maybe that helps

Comment: Does this answer your question? [need implement C# Counter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1353935/need-implement-c-sharp-counter)

Comment: @Skuullkid ok but what's the initial values of Step, Start  and Level ? What do you see when you step through the Decrement method that's the problem ? You want the Level value to decrement but not below Start, in which case you clamp it to the Limit value is that right ?

Comment: @auburg when I start the programm the method Decrement() counts down from the number 15 so it goes 15..14...13.. and so on but what I want to do is I want to make it - after going from 15 to 14 ask the user how much it should go down so like if the user enters "6" it should jump from 14 to 8. and yeah the Level = Limit thing is so it doesn't go below 0

Comment: I added levelalt incase to do that and then the if (levelalt...) but it doesnt work - the user input thing it just keeps going down.

Comment: `if (levelalt < Level)` - how is this going to be true if it's Level you're decrementing (`Level -= Step;`) ? Isn't levelalt always going to be > Level ?

Comment: @auburg but I set levelalt= Level so if I then decrement from Level shouldnt levelalt be bigger?

Comment: yes levelalt will be bigger but your if statement is testing if levelalt is less than level which will never be true (unless Step is a -ve number)

Comment: Change `if (levelalt < Level)` to `if (Step > 0)`.  Or just get rid of the `if` altogether if you want it to ask every time `Decrement()` is called?